# Error C2440 : Cannot convert type in templated class... even though it's the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typename

I'm working with a templated class `List`, which within it defines two classes -- `Node` and `Position`:

```
template <class T>
class List {
public:
    // Nodes in the linked list
    struct Node {
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
        T    item;

        Node() : prev(NULL), next(NULL) {
        }

        Node(T item) : prev(NULL), next(NULL) {
            this->item = item;
        }

        T Item() const { return item; }
    };

    // Object for enumerating the list.
    class POSITION {
        friend class List<T>;

    public:
        POSITION() : pNode(NULL) {
        }

        bool operator==(const POSITION &p) const {
            return pNode == p.pNode;
        }

        bool operator!=(const POSITION &p) const {
            return pNode != p.pNode;
        }

    private:
        typename List<T*>::Node* pNode;

        POSITION(Node *p) : pNode(p)  {
        }
    };

    List() {
        m_anchor.next = &m_anchor;
        m_anchor.prev = &m_anchor;

        m_count = 0;
    }

    POSITION Next(const POSITION pos) {
        if (pos.pNode && (pos.pNode->next != &m_anchor)) {
            return POSITION(pos.pNode->next);
        }
        else {
            return POSITION(NULL);
        }
    }

    protected:
        Node    m_anchor;  // Anchor node for the linked list.
        DWORD   m_count;   // Number of items in the list.
};
```

When I try to compile this class, I get an error C2440:

`'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'List<T*>::Node*' to 'List<T*>::Node*'`

And it points to line within the function `List::Next(const Position pos)`:

`return POSITION(pos.pNode->next);`

What I'm confused about is the error message -- there doesn't seem to be any reason that a `List<T*>::Node*` can't be converted to a `List<T*>::Node*` when they're the same type... I imagine that this is due to the templated class and I probably need a `typename` somewhere, but I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us? Also please include the full and complete error output, including any informational notes. And add a comment in the code itself where you get the error.

Comment: `POSITION(Node *p) : pNode(p)` shouldn't compile. Here, `Node` is `List<T>::Node`, while `pNode` points to `List<T*>::Node`. You probably meant `typename List<T>::Node* pNode;` (note no star in `List<T>`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that was exactly it... great work with the eagle eyes!  I thought I had checked for anything dumb like that but I suppose I missed it!